# shell command in python for sha

Tags: python

```
import os
from subprocess import call

call('(find $readDir -type f -print0  | sort -z | xargs -0 sha1sum; find $readDir \( -type f -o -type d \) -print0 | sort -z | xargs -0 stat -c '\%n \%a') | sha1sum')

SyntaxError: invalid token
```

Can someone tell me which characters need to be escaped here? I thought it was the percent signs but that's not working either. I'm looking to get the sha for the contents of a folder.

Comment: You are using a single quotes inside a single quotes for another purpose than closing a `string` literal? When you start a Python string literal with single quotes always escape single quotes. Same  applies for double quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not dig into your command itself, but to make it work, you can remove the escaping hassle by using triple quotes and "raw" string:

```
call(r'''(find $readDir -type f -print0  | sort -z | xargs -0 sha1sum; find $readDir \( -type f -o -type d \) -print0 | sort -z | xargs -0 stat -c '%n %a') | sha1sum''', shell=True)
```

Also, you need to add `shell=True`, for that command to be passed to your shell interpreter.

That being said, it'd be a better idea to walk through your directory and calculate the hashes in pure python, not calling any shell. Here's an example on how to do it:

As a suggestion here's a way:

```
import os
import hashlib

def sha1OfFile(filepath):
    sha = hashlib.sha1()
    with open(filepath, 'rb') as f:
        while True:
            block = f.read(2**10) # Magic number: one-megabyte blocks.
            if not block: break
            sha.update(block)
        return sha.hexdigest()

for (path, dirs, files) in os.walk('.'):
  for file in files:
    print('{}: {}'.format(os.path.join(path, file),  sha1OfFile(os.path.join(path, file))))
```

Comment: I usually do python3 per default (I stopped coding for 2 a couple of years ago), but that code is compatible for both. Hint: when in doubt, you can try it in the REPL and see if it yells! ☺

Comment: Thanks for the hint. So this code will give me a unique sha for each file, how would you then produce a unique sha to represent the folder and all its contents?

Comment: There's no good way of doing it. You could make a hash of a listing of files+size within the folder, or a hash of the listing of files+hash, or a hash of the concatenated output of all files within the folder, or a hash of zip (or tar) with all the folders files. I'd advice you to make a new question with that, and see what the answers would look like. If you post the link to your new question here, I might give you my take on that.